# GWT DevMode issue

Tags: java, google-chrome, gwt

I developed a GWT widget using vaadin 6. I need to use DevMode (Hosted mode) for testing the widget. I am using Eclipse (Helios). When running the DevMode I tested for IE,FF and chrome, my browser able to  get connect to the GWT codeserver:9997 but  got the following issue;

```
    00:14:51.014 [ERROR] Failed to load module 'com.example.testing.TestingWidgetset' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0' at 127.0.0.1:53754
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: warningThreshold    
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.getCompilerOptions(JdtCompiler.java:400)    
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.<init>(JdtCompiler.java:228)   
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:689)     
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:215)  
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:406)   
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:299)     
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:325)     
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase$UiBrowserWidgetHostImpl.createModuleSpaceHost(DevModeBase.java:105)   
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:190)    
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)   
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)     
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like some JARs are clashing.

You don't happen to have multiple JDT version in the path? I remember some problems with projects using GWT and JasperReports, since those depend on different version of JDT.

Make sure the GWT SDK bundle is on top in the Build Path. Moving the GWT SDK bundle to the top of the classpath in Eclipse should be easy. The Maven build can be fixed by using the configuration `<gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>` in the *gwt-maven-plugin*.